# Following document set

Tags: 2013, document-set, social, following

Am I missing something?
It looks like I can't follow a document set in a document library. I can indeed follow any document inside the document set, but not the set itself. Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible to follow Document Set since Social Actor supports  only the following [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.social.spsocialactortype.aspx):

- `User`   A user
- `Document`   A document.
- `Site`   A site.
- `Tag`  A tag

But you could consider the following approach. The idea is to follow Document Set content (files).  The solution consists of:

- getting `Document Set` files
- follow files in document set

**JavaScript example**

```
function startFollowing(webUrl,fileUrl){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/social.following/follow";
    var actor = {
         "actor":{
             "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"},
             "ActorType":1,
             "ContentUri": fileUrl,
             "Id":null
          }
    };         
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'POST',null,actor);
}


function getFiles(webUrl,folderUrl){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')/files";         
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}


function followFiles(webUrl,folderUrl)
{
    return getFiles(webUrl,folderUrl).then(function(data){
        var files = data.d.results;
        if(files.length == 0) return;
        var fileUrl = webUrl + '/' + folderUrl + '/' + files[0].Name; //server absolute file url
        data = startFollowing(webUrl,fileUrl);
        for (var i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
          (function (i) {
             data = data.then(function() {
                 fileUrl = webUrl + '/' + folderUrl + '/' + files[i].Name;
                 return startFollowing(webUrl,fileUrl);
             });
          }(i));
        }     
    });
}
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined' || headers == null){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Usage

Assume a `Documents` library contains `Guides` document set, then the following example demonstrates how to follow files in document set:

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
followFiles(webUrl,'Documents/Guides');
```